# Enter a new line programmatically

Tags: c++, string

I have a `vector of std::string` with a text, which have some several lines.(strings). Those lines are elements of the vector.

I choose the number of a range, for example: `0 and 2` and the chosen range is deleted and I insert a new string, one string, in the beginning of the vector (where I have deleted).

`But I would like`, when I enter a string and type **'\n'** in the same string, `to see in the outputting result text which will consist of two lines.`

For getting a string with `spaces`, I use `std::getline()`:

```
std::cout << "Enter insreting text: ";
std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, text);
```

**In console mode:**

> `Enter insreting text:  hello \n Bye`
>
> My wishing result should be
>
> hello
>
> bye

Might be I am not right using `std::getline()` for getting a string. Any hints, please?

Comment: If you're typing \n then it's not a control code, it's plain text of \ and n. You need to search the string for instances of \n, but not \\n and replace with endl. Then output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string text;

std::cout << "Enter inserting text: ";
std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, text);

std::string::size_type pos = text.find("\\n");
while (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    text.replace(pos, 2, "\n");
    pos = text.find("\\n", pos+1);
}

std::cout << text;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/5ip5xu)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, the text captured by `std::getline()` if you input

```
hello \n Bye
```

is

```
"hello \\n Bye"
```

shown as a literal.

To output

```
hello
 Bye
```

you need to replace the occurrence of `"\\n"` with `"\n"`.

@Remy already posted the code how to do that in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48309284/9212993).